# problem with header Image elements do not have explicit width and height pagespeed says

Tags: image, blogger

why pagespeed keep saying Set an explicit width and height on image elements to reduce layout shifts and improve CLS.

my css

```
#header img{
max-height:27px;
max-width:300px;
vertical-align:middle;}
```

[my website url](https://ezzeddinisalm.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 0):

To remove this warning, you need to write it in the `img` tag, for example :

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="your title" width="500" height="250">
```

Comment: I know but how? look at my code it's widget
========
<b:widget-setting name='displayUrl'>http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-dGRUOn7Mzj4/X46U3MTVQFI/AAAAAAAABEM/4MNOAtVlmdUP7XFRVlo1BDaswZQ91uyMwCK4BGAYYCw/s1600/Untitled-7.webp</b:widget-setting>